# Angular JS Data loading Before Page Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wanna load data before AngularJS Page Load. I'm using bootstrap and JQuery as well along Angualr. Main problem is that i have table on page and used JQuery for pagination and other filters including responsiveness as well.

Now what happened is, that Page loads all JQuery and later my data comes on page and nothing works like pagination etc. I do following workaround:

```
 <script>
      $(function () {
        //  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
          setTimeout(
                  function() 

                      $('#example1').DataTable({
                          "paging": true,
                          "lengthChange": false,
                          "searching": true,
                          "ordering": true,
                          "info": true,
                          "autoWidth": true,
                          "scrollX": true
                        });
                  }, 500);

      });
    </script>
```

I added manual delay to wait JQuery, so that page loads its data before.

Can anybody tells good solution, how to  make sure that data is loaded before Page HTML renders ?

Comment: This is just wrong. You should wrap your jquery code inside an angular directive instead.

Comment: Means you want to load data after document ready?

Comment: You can use the routes resolve to load whatever data you want before it loads

Comment: Yes I want load data before document ready

Comment: Angular has the ability to paginate, order, and filter tables; native, in their ng-repeat directive. You might try making an api call via angular service then load that data into a table. No reason to stitch together jquery and angular when the functionality is already available.

Comment: You could ng-cloak the body and apply a function call to your jquery script and put the script in an angular controller.

Comment: I don't think you need any jQuery to paginate. Write your own pagination directive or use any of pre written pagination directives. You can look for following one even

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/01/31/AngularJS-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx

Comment: Hello Everyone, I really respect your thoughts to not use JQuery, But there is some cases where you don't have other option as JQuery Datatables have several features like responsiveness etc, that can't be achieved using AngualrJS only...

Answer (score 9):

I'd strongly suggest against using jQuery for your pagination.  There are other solutions that will keep the Angular magic working for you such as ui-grid, smart-table, etc.  These require pretty low effort on your part.

If you really want to keep on this path though, you might be able to get what you want with `$routeProvider.when`'s resolve.  When the route is requested, the resolve block will run any promises first, and wait for them to resolve before going to that route.  Resolve can also pass that data into the controller of the route:

```
.when('/route', {
    ...,
    resolve: {
        dataYouWant: function(DataGettingService) {
            return DataGettingService.get();
        }
    }
})
```

[routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a possible solution. You might also use a directive instead of a controller

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .factory('repository', function ($http) {
        var loadData = function () {
            return $http... ;//make http call here and return the promise
        };

        return {
            loadData: loadData
        };
    })
    .controller('myCtrl', function (repository) {
        repository.loadData().then(function(data) {
            // use loaded data here
            $('#example1').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "scrollX": true
            });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your jQuery code with Angular in some way. Here is the directive try.

```
app.directive('jqueryCallDirective' , function() {
   return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                 ...
            });
        }
   }
});
```

Then use ng-if deferred render for your element:

```
<div id="example1" ng-if="hasData" jquery-call-directive> ... </div>
```

and then set `$scope.hasData = true` in appropriate time on appropriate scope (or just on $rootScope if this is acceptable). Hope it helps!